# Varying Images per Print

Tags: gimp, data-merge

I want to send out a postcard to several thousand people with a specific image on each just for the recipient.  I have designed the common background in GIMP and have my series of specific images.

In GIMP (or a similar program), is there a way to vary the graphics (similar to Mail Merge) in each by adding in the specific picture?

My other options currently are to put both images into Word MailMerge or create some code in C# that combines both of them into one image and iterates through the images, but I'm curious if there's a simpler and/or ready-made solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can merge the images in a shell script using [ImageMagick's `compose`](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/compose/).

Comment: Once you get the command tested, an incredibly direct way to get get a shell script for this is to use a mail merge to create them all. Assuming there are per-file alignment tweaks/aspect ratio adjustments.